# Apollo Suit sublimation coolers

Tags: apollo-program, spacesuits, eva

Should there be a visible steam plume from the Apollo astronauts sublimation cooler in the lunar EVA videos?

Comment: Look around you and you won't see water in the air even though there's plenty of it. You see clouds because water forms drops big enough to scatter light.

Comment: Pure water steam is invisible. If there are tiny droplets of liquid water within the steam, you see the mist caused by the droplets, but you don't see the water vapour itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_Cooling_and_Ventilation_Garment):

> As an example, during the Apollo 12 commander's first EVA (of 3 hrs, 44 minutes), 4.75 lb of feedwater were sublimated, and this dissipated 894.4 Btu / hr.

That's 2.154 kg of water over 224 minutes, or 10g/min, or 0.16g/s.

Water vapor is invisible to the naked eye ([2](http://vsgc.odu.edu/src/Conf09/UnderGrad%20Papers/Ojo%20-%20Paper.pdf), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303804/how-are-water-vapors-not-visible)). What you see e.g. when boiling water is not the water vapor itself, it's small droplets of liquid water (fog, mist, steam) which are suspended in the air and carried by the air flow.

With only so little mass escaping the suits, those droplets do not form in any substantial amount, and there is no air that could carry them around. Thus, there is nothing to see.

Comment: 0.16g/s is about three small drops (a drop, as used in medicine, for eye droppers or stomach drops is 0.05ml). Drip three drops per second on a hot stove and see if you can spot the vapor...

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I was under the impression that steam would immediately condense in the vacuum of space and freeze.  I was thinking crystals should form and fall to the ground.

Comment: When the astronauts take a leak while on a mission and expel the result into space, it boils violently. The vapor then passes immediately into the solid state (a process known as desublimation), and you end up with a cloud of very fine crystals of frozen urine.

Comment: @TimFinch The urine is expelled in liqid form, not geaseous form, and its much, much more - if you look at Table 1 in https://history.nasa.gov/SP-368/s6ch2.htm, about 1-2 liters each dump.... (the collection system had a max capacity of 3L).

Comment: @Polygnome  The point I make is steam or vapor cannot exist in the vacuum of space.  If anything at all was visible it would be ice crystals.  I understand the flow rate is small but I believe it is artificially small.  I think the heat of radiation from direct sunlight and the heat of conduction from the feet plus body heat would require a much larger flow rate than indicated.  I don't think they could carry enough water for a 3 hour mission in direct sunlight.  That is one man's opinion.

Comment: @Tim Finch Water vapor can exist in the vacuum of space. A rocket engine working with liquid hydrogen and oxygen does eject hot water vapor. But any gas ejected into the vacuum of space will spread until there is a big distance from one gas molecule to the next one. This is true for gases like nitrogen and helium but also for water vapor. You should consider the energy that is necessary to vaporize the water. 2257 kJ/kg is needed for water, with 2.154 kg of water over 224 minutes, this is a heat power of 361 W. The direct sunlight does not heat much due to the white surface.

Comment: @TimFinch: a bit of clarification on what Uwe said: water phase change graph does quite a bit of "gymnastics" for pressures below 0.01 bar, and while ice is much more likely at ~0.001 bar and less, note how little of pressure differential that is! Going from 0.01 bar to 0.001 bar is  equally "vigorous" than going from 1.01 bar to (1010hPa) to 1.001 bar (1001hPa) - not even a perceptible breeze. Meaning dispersion (drop) of pressure is nowhere near to instantaneous; a single "puff" of steam at ~0.05 bar (above triple point!) can linger for minutes before its pressure drops to "vacuum".

Comment: @SF.  It confuses me why you use a positive pressure in the vacuum of space.  I would expect the vacuum of space to be a negative number and I have to believe that water could not exist in the liquid form at all.  I believe the transformation from water to ice would be instantaneous.  As a matter of fact, I believe the heat exchanger should freeze with a coating of ice after a few minutes.

Comment: @TimFinch: Vacuum of space is 0.[very little]. Atmosphere at sea level is ~1 bar. There's no such thing as negative pressure. There's a scale that's offset by 1 bar (e.g. Psi-guage) which is used in technology, but rarely useful in space applications.

Comment: @TimFinch for absolute pressure there is no negative pressure. The best vacuum is defined to be zero pressure and there could not be a lower pressure than a perfect vacuum.  
Differential pressure is a different thing, it is the pressure difference between two vessels. Each vessel has a positive or zero absolute pressure but the differential pressure may be positive or negative. In aircondition system the pressure at different points of the system may be higher or lower than the air pressure outside the building. In this case small differential pressure values, pos. or neg. does make sense.

Comment: Vacuum Ranges
Pressure 
(Pa)
Low vacuum 1x105 to 3x103
Medium vacuum 3x103 to 1x10-1
High vacuum 1x10-1 to 1x10-7
Ultra high vacuum 1x10-7 to 1x10-10
Extremely high vacuum 1x10-10
Perfect vacuum 0
Outer space 1x10-4 to < 3x10-15

Comment: I still believe sublimation would freeze the heat heat exchanger rendering it useless after a few minutes of operation.

Comment: @TimFinch The tiny holes of the heat exchanger are filled with ice, but by sublimation this ice turns to vapour. If all the ice of one hole is sublimated, a little drop of water fills the hole and turns toice again. The heat exchanger plate is not useless when all holes are filled with ice, that is the normal operation to avoid loss of too much water.

Comment: @TimFinch the different vacuum pressure values in Pascal you mentioned are all positive, only the powers of ten are negative. There are no negative pressure values listed, only small and very small values.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I was under the impression that sublimation was the process of extracting the latent heat of vaporization from liquid water. Once the outside of the heat exchanger was coated with ice the ice would act as a thermal barrier to further heat transfer from sublimation.  Did I misconstrue this?